# Use text as a mask on background image

Tags: html, css

I have a nice background on my page, and I want my text header to act as a *mask* to cut through its containing div and have the background as a texture.

Can I do this in *CSS* or do I have to open up *Photoshop*?

Comment: you may have to open up photoshop just to show us what the end result needs to look like :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Limited browser support, but `background-clip` can get you this effect: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ExperimentsBackgroundClipText/ (Hit the Animate buttons for more fun)

Using SVG you can do it like this: http://people.opera.com/dstorey/images/newyorkmaskexample.svg (View source to see what is actually done, see [reference article](http://my.opera.com/dstorey/blog/using-svg-masks-for-cut-out-text-effects) too)

Using a background image and then CSS, you could do this: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/texturise-web-type-css

Comment: Opera and Netmagazine links are broken :(

Answer (score 6):

As CSS-Tricks shows in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/), 'image behind text' can be done as such:

```
h1 {
   color: white;  /* Fallback: assume this color ON TOP of image */
   background: url(images/fire.jpg) no-repeat; /* Set the backround image */
   -webkit-background-clip: text; /* clip the background to the text inside the tag*/
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* make the text transparent so 
                                          * the background shows through*/
}
```

But it isn't guaranteed to work on all browsers, so they suggest a few work arounds, like [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Here's what it looks like when it works:

[image: What it looks like when it works]

Answer (score 4):

There is a `background-clip: text` property in CSS3, although it doesn't work in every browser.  See [here](http://www.webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To extend @sgress454's answer. Nowadays, `background-clip: text` works in Firefox and Edge, but its browser compatibility is still not full. Safari does not and Chrome partially (It is supported with the prefixed version of the property only. According to the [WebKit blog](https://webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/), text decorations or shadows are not included in the clipping.). `background-clip: text` is still what you are looking for:

> background-clip: text;
>
> The background is painted within (clipped to) the foreground text.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

Demo:

```css
body {background: black;}

div {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543005472-1b1d37fa4eae?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60), black;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>This background clips to the text.</div>
```