# How to make text clip inside navbar?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website and i want to clip(mask) text from navbar. The text becomes like a hole in the navbar and background image is seen through it. How to do this?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g4mYX/2/)

```
//css code
text{
    background-image: inherit;     
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Can I use text as a mask so the background image shows inside the text only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924800/css-can-i-use-text-as-a-mask-so-the-background-image-shows-inside-the-text-only)

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS property called [background-clip](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-clip) that seems to do do what you're looking for. It's is unfortunatly not supported before IE9 (but works on other main broswers : Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari).

Depending on the importance of this implementation you can always have a different rendering for older IE versions and use `background-clip` in any other context.

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8q5h/) and comment to tell me if it's what you were looking for!

---

**EDIT** : I misunderstood the initial request. I'll try to find a suitable solution for the actual question! Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you sure about IE9+ and FF support ?

Comment: I took this information from the [Mozilla Developper Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip), it appears to be supported by FF since 4.0.

Comment: background-clip: border-box, padding-box, content-box is supported. background-clip: text isn't. Check your source.

Comment: @Kad what this person want is, background image is fixed in the bg and a hole should be formed through the white box. so when he scrolls the slider, bg image is seen thru this text.