# How to make text appear as an image

Tags: css, image, text, heading

So I know the title is a bit confusing, so I'll try to clear it up a bit here:

I want my to have a heading with a picture in the *exact* shape of a letter. Almost like a picture is hidden behind a div but the text cuts 'holes' in it and allows someone to see the image in the shape of the letter.

I realize just how unclear this is, but that's kind of doubly why I couldn't search for it because I don't know how to describe it.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924800/css-can-i-use-text-as-a-mask-so-the-background-image-shows-inside-the-text-only

Comment: That looks like what I needed! Thanks!